# Is it possible to send an email to a client which includes a report

Tags: apex, email, reporting

Is it possible to use Apex class (or preferably flow only) to send email to a client such that the email body includes some text first (like greetings) then a report data in a table or even list view ( I know it’s possible to send it as attachment)

Thanks in advance.

edit: I found a simple solution using flow only [here](https://salesforcetime.com/2023/11/02/how-to-send-email-with-a-record-table-in-flow/)

Comment: I've used the HTML table approach myself if I didn't want to use apex getContent() method